# View SVN versions of a site in the browser

Tags: svn

Sample scenario:

I have a web project and an associated SVN repository. I have 1 file *index.html* and 3 committed revisions of that file:

revision 3:

```
<p>This is revision 3</p>
```

revision 2:

```
<p>This is revision 2</p>
```

revision 1:

```
<p>This is revision 1</p>
```

This is located in the repo root at http:127.0.0.1/svnhistoryviewer/index.html

When I view this in the browser I get

This is revision 3

(as expected because that's the latest).

Is there a way I can view the previous revisions in the front end? Also, can I do this with tags of the project?

Been searching a while without luck. I did read something about appending `/!svn/bc/REVISION_NUMBER`to the URL, but it's just 404ing when I try that.

**EDIT:**

Further answers to this question have suggested that ?p=REVISIONNUMBER should pull up that version of the file, however I've had no luck.

I am clearly missing something fundamental about svn in general here. Does the working copy have to be running on some sort of 'svn server' or should a basic Apache HTTP server work? My set up is basically an Apache server running on an Ubunutu VM with a web root that happens to contain an svn repository containing a site that was checked out from SourceForge.

Comment: You didn't say which tool you're using to browse your SVN repository from a web browser.

Comment: I'm not using a tool, just viewing a web project in a browser which has an associated svn repo. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is a "web project" and an "associated" svn repo? If you mean that the web server serves files from a directory which is a working copy of an SVN project, then there's no way to view any SVN history. You're just serving files, and some of these files happen to be in .svn directories. Or do you mean that you're accessing an SVN repo through HTTP, using a web browser?

Comment: A web project as in a collection of files that define a web application. The web app is located on a virtual machine with Apache so I can view it in the browser. I have set up svn source control for the web root of the app. Is what I want to do impossible in the configuration I just described?

Answer (score 2):

There are tools that allow you to browse your Subversion repository via a web browser. For example, [Sventon](http://sventon.org) is a favorite of mine. However, these tools let you view your files as .... files. They purposefully remove all special entities from the files in order to show you your file as it appears. This allows you to integrate your Subversion repository with tools like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) and [Jira](http://atlassian.com). These tools will link to a particular revision of your Subversion repository via Sventon, and then you can click on the link, see the file information, do diffs, etc. This does not sound like what you want to do.

However, you've mentioned **appending** *`/!svn/bc/REVISION_NUMBER` to the URL*. That's not how it works. You put this *between* the URL root and your repository directory structure:

```
http://svn.vegicorp/svn/repo_name/trunk/foo/bar   #This shows you the latest revision

http://svn.vegicorp/svn/repo_name/!svn/bc/1000/trunk/foo/bar #Revision 1000
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to install anything else server side to make that work? My svn root directory is actually the same as the web root but I tried: http://127.0.0.1:5678/svnhistory/!svn/bc/2/index.php. No luck though unfortunately. Yeah, I had used one called Codesion once.

Comment: You shouldn't have to install anything. Is the root of your repository `http://127.0.0.1:5678/svnhistory`, and `index.html` is sitting right on the root? Are you using Apache https or svnserve? The directions I gave work for SVN Serve. The directions I gave were for a Apache httpd installation.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I'm just using a standard Apache2 install, httpd I guess.

Comment: Why the port number 5678? Is there a reason port 80 doesn't work?

Comment: oh yeh should have mentioned that port 5678 is mapped to port 80 of my virtual server, so it's port 80 on linux and port 80 on my mac

Comment: In your Apache configuration, is `svnhistory` your virtual directory?

Comment: Ah, maybe that could be it. It's actually a sub-directory of the web root. I use it for test projects. Should I create a new virtual host do you think? Thanks for all your help

Comment: If `svnhistory` a sub directory of the webroot, then it should be something like: `http:/127.0.0.1:5678/!svn/bc/1000/svnhistory/index.php`. However, I've never seen an Apache http URL for Subversion without an Apache virtual directory. Of course you've mentioned this is a VM, so that might be the exception.

Answer (score 0):

- If you reporitory is http-repository
- If you haven't any special "repository browsers" on top of clean Apache

you can see **any** historical **revisions** of **any** repository **objects** using special suffix in URL

`http://URL-in-REPO?p=REV`, where REV is number of revision

Comment: Argh, no it's not having this. It's just showing the latest version regardless of the ?p=2 or ?p=4 etc. My repository was made on SourceForge and I did notice when initially checking-out that there were 3 options: RW, RO and HTTP, I chose RW. Does this mean I haven't got a http-repository? Is there a way I can check? and URL-in-REPO is just the URL of the resource that happens to be under version control right?

Comment: @AdamWaite - three accesstypes in SF are just access types for the same repo and *can be used simultaneously*, and [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Subversion#Access) I see only one, https type of repo. `URL-in-REPO` is, yes, path to something inside your repo. If you'll write your repo-url, I'll try to be more concrete. And ?p= syntax must work in **any case**

Comment: It just does not work so I am clearly missing something fundamental about this or svn in general here. Does the working copy have to be running on some sort of 'svn server' or should a basic Apache HTTP server work? My set up is basically an Apache server with a web root that happens to contain an svn repository containing a site that was checked out from SourceForge.

Comment: If our site is *working copy* (or *exported repository*) you can't use suffix, which is usable only in case of **direct access to http-repository**. I.e - you can see history from SF-repo, not site